# Getting Saved Data from Broadcast Receiver (BOOT_COMPLETED alarm)

Tags: android

I have a broadcast receiver for receiving the 'BOOT_COMPLETED' event.  What I want to do in the OnReceive method is to re-schedule an alarm whose time is pre-defined by the user.  How would I go about getting the alarm time that the user entered into the application?  I tried looking at SharedPreferences but these don't seem to be accessible out-with Activity classes.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I could go about getting this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to set the alarm at boot time. You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) to handle that for you. You can even set repeating alarms with it.

Comment: I use alarmmanager but the alarms are cleared when the device is rebooted. ' Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.'

Comment: Ah gotcha. You can used SharedPreferences. Just get the one from your application context because you can access that from your activities and broadcast receiver.